# Is it possible to count SYN and ACK flags separately in a single rule in Snort?

Tags: network, ids, snort

I want to write a rule for Snort to detect lost traffic in the network. Is it possible to write a rule that, by combining two flags, SYN and ACK, it declares that if the number of SYNs to the server exceeds a certain number, but at the same time, the number of ACKs from the server is less than a certain number?